# forms.ModelChoiceField and Internationalization

Tags: python, django, django-forms

How can I support i18n in forms? I would like to use `{% translate "SOMETHING" %}` in a template. Or should I just use `_()` in views.py only for the selectbox, in order to translate these strings?

I do not want to use model i18n addons.